# Is constexpr if with initializer guaranteed by the standard? 'constexpr(constexpr auto x = f(); x) { }'

Tags: c++, clang, constexpr, c++17

I can't find any information about new C++17 if initializer syntax 
and 'constexpr if' in:

http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2016/p0128r1.html

Nevertheless, the syntax is supported by **Clang-HEAD**...

```
constexpr auto f() { return true; }
int main() {
    if constexpr(constexpr auto x = f(); x) { }
}
```

online code here -> http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/dj3a9ChvjhlNc8nr

Is the `constexpr if` with initializer guaranteed by the standard, as `constexpr if` is just an "`if` with `constexpr`" or it's not guaranteed and has to be explicitly added to the standard?

Comment: There was a discussion about whether we want this or not in EWG, and the point about Boost.Hana-style metaprogramming being *greatly* improved by using both features at the same time (as opposed to just having `if constexpr`), hence it was agreed that we want it (with almost everyone agreeing with it and one vote against).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Selection statements with initializer](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0305r1.html#constexpr) proposal mentions `if constexpr`, and states "the facilities of `if constexpr` work just as well with the extended `if` statement from this proposal".

The specification about `if` statement with initializer in [N4606](http://wg21.link/N4606) [stmt.if]p3 explicitly allows use of `if constexpr`.

Here is what N4606 [stmt.if]p3 says:

> An if statement of the form
>
> ```
> if constexpr[opt] ( init-statement condition ) statement
> ```
>
> is equivalent to
>
> ```
> {
>   init-statement
>   if constexpr[opt] ( condition ) statement
> }
> ```
>
> and an if statement of the form
>
> ```
> if constexpr[opt] ( init-statement condition ) statement else statement
> ```
>
> is equivalent to
>
> ```
> {
>   init-statement
>   if constexpr[opt] ( condition ) statement else statement
> }
> ```
>
> except that names declared in the init-statement are in the same declarative region as those declared in the condition.